# Command substitution. Spawned process name is identical to the parent one

Tags: bash, process, command-substitution

This script

```
$ cat csub.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do 
  sleep 5
  AVAR=$(date; sleep 2)
done
```

when started, makes a process appear in the ps output:

```
ps -eLf|egrep '[c]sub.sh|PID'
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jimmy    31364 23445 31364  0    1 00:33 pts/7    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./csub.sh
```

which is quite predictable
as well as the fact that `$(date; sleep 2)` spawns another process

Surprising is that the spawned process has *identical* CMD displayed

```
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jimmy    31364 23445 31364  0    1 00:33 pts/7    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./csub.sh
jimmy    31433 31364 31433  0    1 00:33 pts/7    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./csub.sh
```

I added sleep to be able to catch the process into the ps output, otherwise one have much less chances to, because it's too short.
As you see the spawned process 31433 has 31364 as its parent.
I would expect the spawned process has some different CMD mentioning what it deals with, e.g date or sleep command.
For cases when there are multiple command substitutions, how could I distinguish them when I see a spawned process appeared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual page, section 2 for `fork()`:

> `fork()` creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. The
>   new process, referred to as the child, is an exact duplicate of the
>   calling process, referred to as the parent, except for the following
>   points:
>
> - The child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match the ID of any existing process group (`setpgid(2)`).
> - The child's parent process ID is the same as the parent's process ID.
> - The child does not inherit its parent's memory locks (`mlock(2)`, `mlockall(2)`).
> - Process resource utilizations (`getrusage(2)`) and CPU time counters (`times(2)`) are reset to zero in the child.
> - The child's set of pending signals is initially empty (`sigpending(2)`).
> - The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (`semop(2)`).
> - The child does not inherit record locks from its parent (`fcntl(2)`).
> - The child does not inherit timers from its parent (`setitimer(2)`, `alarm(2)`, `timer_create(2)`).
> - The child does not inherit outstanding asynchronous I/O operations from its parent (`aio_read(3)`, `aio_write(3)`), nor does it inherit any
>     asynchronous I/O contexts from its parent (see `io_setup(2)`).

Not on this list is the invocation command line of the process, so that will be identical to its parent.  You can tell children apart from their parents because the child's PPID (Parent PID) will be the originating process's PID.

Comment: Thanks for the good reference, Does Parent-Child relation mean there's always a fork behind it? That would mean children always have parent's name (CMD in ps notation), which is apparently false. otherwise all the linux processes would be named init. Is there something bash-specific in my case? Could you explain that please?

Comment: Only new processes spawned by `fork()` inherit the name of their parents.  All processes do _have_ a parent, which will become `init` if the parent dies without reaping its child.

Comment: I am afraid I am still missing the gist. When I see ps -ef output I can see children of same parent having different names. 
Here's my sample http://hastebin.com/enawowoweh.hs
Following your last comment, how can i interpret that?
Are they  a) not new | b) not spawned | c) spawned not by fork ?

Comment: `ps -ef | sort | less` is a pipeline; the processes are not `fork`ed from `bash`; in this cash `bash` is spawning entirely _new_ processes, not forks of itself.

Comment: Yes, that's the point i missed - spawning is not necessarily forking. Finally got it.
Thank you for making me get it.

Comment: @Tagwint The command listed by `ps` changes when the process calls the `execve` system call to load a new program image into the existing process. When the shell launches an external program, it first calls `fork` to create a new process (which doesn't change the command line) and then `execve` (which loads code from an executable file, and at the same time changes the command line).