# Why does pgrep return randomly a wrong pid?

Tags: linux, bash, process, lsof, pgrep

In the past I used pid-files to guarantee race-condition safe execution of scripts. But this had the downside, that the pid-file was not deleted if the kernel killed the script somehow. So sometimes manual interaction was needed (remove the pid file, killing some sub processes).

Finally I came up to a solution which checks if a script is running by using `pgrep` and kills really old processes that shouldn't exist anymore:

```
while read -r pid cmd; do
  # check if pid or parent pid belong to current script execution
  if [[ $pid == "$$" ]] || [[ $(ps -o ppid= -p "$pid" | xargs) == "$$" ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  # avoid re-execution of script within 12 hours (43200 seconds)
  if [[ $(date +%s --d="now - $( stat -c%X "/proc/$pid" ) seconds") -lt 43200 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Script is already running!"
    exit
  fi
  # kill outdated script executions
  if kill -9 "$pid"; then
    echo "Warning: Outdated script execution ($pid) has been killed!"
  fi
done < <(pgrep -af "/bin/bash $(basename "$(readlink -f "$0")")")
```

This works on hundreds of servers and thousands of script executions without any issues, but in very rare cases it returned an "already running"-error although no other script was executed.

As I was not able to find a bug in my code, I created more debug information:

```
echo "pid: $pid"
echo "cmd: $cmd"
echo "lsof:"
lsof -p "$pid"
echo "/proc/$pid/cmdline:"
xargs -0 <"/proc/$pid/cmdline"
echo "pstree:"
pstree -asp "$pid"
```

And after several weeks it returned this:

```
2023-04-02 06:10:01 Error: Script is already running!
2023-04-02 06:10:01 pid: 3902
2023-04-02 06:10:01 cmd: /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/script.sh
2023-04-02 06:10:01 lsof:
2023-04-02 06:10:01 COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  cwd    DIR    8,3     4096  6291457 /root
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  rtd    DIR    8,3     4096        2 /
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  txt    REG    8,3    77664  2886809 /usr/bin/sed
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  mem    REG    8,3  1936776  5243076 /lib64/libc-2.22.so
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  mem    REG    8,3    10344  2892257 /usr/lib64/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root  mem    REG    8,3   164144  5242936 /lib64/ld-2.22.so
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root    0r  FIFO   0,12      0t0 96041317 pipe
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root    1w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 96037120 pipe
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed     3902 root    2w  FIFO   0,12      0t0 96021482 pipe
2023-04-02 06:10:01 /proc/3902/cmdline:
2023-04-02 06:10:01 sed s/%/%%/g
2023-04-02 06:10:01 pstree:
2023-04-02 06:10:01 systemd,1 --switched-root --system --deserialize 23
2023-04-02 06:10:01   `-cron,3599 -n
2023-04-02 06:10:01       `-cron,3885 -n
2023-04-02 06:10:01           `-fcc-monitor-and,3891 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
2023-04-02 06:10:01               `-fcc-monitor-and,3901 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
2023-04-02 06:10:01                   `-sed,3902 s/%/%%/g
```

As you can see `pgrep` returned `3902`, which is used by a subshell process of the script. Instead I would expect `3891` or `3901` (as in all other executions). Is this a bug of `pgrep` or why isn't it 100% reliable?

Update:
Only for those, who are interested in the final solution:

```
# obtain script vars
script_pid="$$"
script_path=$(readlink -f "$0")

# make script safe against race conditions (can't be executed twice)
while read -r pid; do

  # obtain all parent and child pids
  pid_list=$(pstree --show-parents --show-pids "$pid")

  # ignore list as it was created through current script execution
  if echo "$pid_list" | grep -F "($script_pid)" >/dev/null; then
    continue
  fi

  # verify that pid is part of the list ("pstree --show-parents" returns list, even pid does not exist https://github.com/acg/psmisc/issues/5)
  if ! echo "$pid_list" | grep -F "($pid)" >/dev/null; then
    continue # process does not exist anymore
  fi

  # obtain age of pid
  pid_time=$( stat -c%X "/proc/$pid" 2>/dev/null )
  if [[ ! $pid_time ]]; then
    continue # process does not exist anymore
  fi

  # kill outdated script executions (older than 12 hours / 43200 seconds)
  if [[ $(date +%s --d="now - $pid_time seconds") -gt 43200 ]]; then
    if kill -9 "$pid"; then
      echo "Warning: Outdated script execution ($pid) has been killed!"
    fi

  # we are facing a race condition
  else
    echo "Error: Script is already running!"
    exit 1
  fi

done < <(pgrep -f "^/bin/bash $script_path") # obtain pids that belong to this script
```

Comment: Seems like a race condition. For an extremely brief period, between when the script process forked out to start `sed` and actually `exec`'d `sed`, that child process has the same command line as the parent process, so it got picked up by `pgrep`. But I don't see how this is a problem for your use case, since it would be picking up the child process only when the main script is already running, right?

Comment: The `-a` option to `pgrep` is explained in the man page as, "include process ancestors in the match list".  So the parent process will be included, even when that parent process doesn't match the regular expression.  This sounds like it can be a source of "the wrong pid".

Comment: systemd and tmpfs have ways of dealing with this to prevent the races.

Comment: @muru My problem was in the "several checks" part. I only checked `[[ $pid == "$$" ]] || [[ $(ps -o ppid= -p "$pid" | xargs) == "$$"`. Instead I should have checked all parent and child pids with `pstree -sp "$pid" | grep -oP "(?<=\()[0-9]+(?=\))" | grep -q "$$"`. By that the `sed` process will be skipped, too. Do you have any references for your statement "extremely brief period ... has the same command"? Then feel free to post it as the answer?

Comment: @SottoVoce I'm not using FreeBSD. In other versions of pgrep, `-a` means `
List the full command line as well as the process ID`.

Comment: I found the same question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281758/command-substitution-spawned-process-name-is-identical-to-the-parent-one/281761) and voted for closing mine.

Comment: Your reasons for avoiding pidfiles might be based on a false premise - perhaps you have been relying on the mere _presence_ of the pidfile rather than actually inspecting the process it references?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I could use the pid, which is stored in the pidfile and do the checks / cleanup with that, but the `gprep`-way does not need to create pidfiles and read their content at all. And you even don't need to think about `trap`'s, that delete pidfiles on script interruption. And you never face the problem that someone deletes the pidfile, while forgetting to kill a staling script. Conclusion: Less code and more fail-proof.

Comment: @muru Only a small update: ` | grep -q "$$"` was a bad idea as `$$` creates another race condition as it sometimes seems to have the pid of the invoking pipe command. That's why I now set `script_pid="$$"` at the beginning of the script and use `grep -qF "($script_pid)"` instead (full code in my question if someone is interested).